# replace string value in config.php

Tags: php, settings, backend, configuration-files

I don't know that much about php. I have 3 files in my project.

1st one is system.php, which hold the hole application logic.
here its code:

```
<?php 
    require "config/config_system.php";

    $config = new Config;
    $config-> load('config.php');
// this is way i want to change setting.
    echo $config-> replace("db.host" , "replace value");
?>
```

2nd one is config_system.php, which holds the configuration logic.here its code:

```
<?php 

    class Config {

        protected $data;
        protected $informaton;

        protected $default;

        public function load($file) {

            $this->data = require $file;
            $this->informaton = require $file;

        }

        public function find($key, $default = null) {

            $this->default = $default;

            $segments = explode(".", $key);

            $data = $this->data;

            foreach ($segments as $segment) {
                if (isset($data[$segment])) {
                    $data = $data[$segment];
                } else {
                    $data = $this->default;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return $data;

        }

        public function exists($key) {

            return $this->find($key) !== $this->default;

        }

// this is the function i am trying to make valide
        public function replace($value) {

            $arrayvalues = explode(".", $value);

            $informaton = $this->informaton;

            foreach ($arrayvalues as $arrayvalue) {
                if (isset($informaton[$arrayvalue])) {
                    $informaton = $informaton[$arrayvalue];
                }
            }

            return $arrayvalues;

        }
    }
?>
```

and 3rd one is config.php, which holds the configurations.

```
<?php 

    return [
        "installation"      => [
                                 // this is the value I want to change via a function to true.
            "create_db"         => "false",
            "create_table"      => "false"

        ],
        "db"                => [
            "host"              => "localhost",
            "user_name"         => "root",
            "password"          => ""
        ]
    ];

?>
```

Now I want to change some setting via a function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function replace ($keyset, $value){
$key_parse = explode(".",keyset);
$this->data[$key_parse[0]][$key_parse[1]] = $value;
return $this->data;
}
```

Use this function in your config_system.php

Comment: Hay thanks for the answer. but the function is showing error.  explode() expects at least 2 parameters

Comment: sorry for typo mistake.. It